# how can I edit user profile information in sharepoint via powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On our SharePoint Enterprise 2010 (not Sp1) our user profile sync is broken so changes to user profiles in AD do not get pushed to SharePoint. I know of a way to directly edit user profile information via powershell or cmd but I am unsure of the exact process to go about completing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great sample script I've used to perform bulk updates to the user profiles via PowerShell.  http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/07/19/bulk-update-sharepoint-2010-user-profile-properties/